# create a scala function that generates ordered list of integers of length N

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a simple function that builds an iterator of all the lists of two positive integers (x,y) that are <1000 and have x <= y

```
def twoIntsIterator(): Iterator[List[Int]] = {
  for {
    x <- Iterator.range(1, 1000)
    y <- Iterator.range(x, 1000)
  } yield List(x, y)
}
```

How would you implement a function `intsListIterator(n: Int, limit: Int)` that geneneralizes the list creation to lists of variable length? Such a function would produce the same output of the one above for n=2 and limit=1000. If called with n=3 and limit=4 it would return an iterator that produces the following:

```
List(1,1,1)
List(1,1,2)
List(1,1,3)
List(1,2,2)
List(1,2,3)
List(1,3,3)
List(2,2,2)
List(2,2,3)
List(2,3,3)
List(3,3,3)
```

N.B.: I used iterators but they could have been views, the point is the variable list length

Comment: Is order important? E.g. can 123 come before 122?

Comment: yes, but you have a good answer below (eastsun) that works with a different order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use recursion:

```
def produce(n: Int, limit: Int, k: Int = 1): Iterator[List[Int]] = {
  Iterator.range(k, limit) flatMap {
    case x if n > 1 => produce(n - 1, limit, x).map(x :: _)
    case x => Iterator(List(x))
  }
}
```

Or with for-comprehension:

```
def produce(n: Int, limit: Int, k: Int = 1): Iterator[List[Int]] = for {
   x <- k to limit - 1 iterator;
   y <- if (n > 1) produce(n - 1, limit, x) else Iterator(Nil)
} yield x :: y
```

Comment: something's wrong, intsListIterator(5,5) produces Lists of 4 elements

Comment: I also translated this to for comprehension but yours looks more compact

Comment: added for-comprehension

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution:

```
scala> def gen(n: Int, limit: Int): Iterator[List[Int]] = n match {
     |   case 0 => Iterator(Nil)
     |   case _ => for(t <- 1 to limit iterator;s <- gen(n-1, t)) yield s:+t
     | }
```

**EDIT**
The following method generating all `List`s with size `n` and its elements satisfy `start <= x < end`, you can def `intsListIterator` by

```
def intsListIterator(n: Int, limit: Int) = gen(n, 1, limit)

scala> def gen(n: Int, start: Int, end: Int): Iterator[List[Int]] = n match {
     |   case 0 => Iterator(Nil)
     |   case _ => for(i <- Iterator.range(start, end);s <- gen(n-1,i,end)) yield i::s
     | }
gen: (n: Int, start: Int, end: Int)Iterator[List[Int]]

scala> gen(3, 1, 4) foreach println
List(1, 1, 1)
List(1, 1, 2)
List(1, 1, 3)
List(1, 2, 2)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1, 3, 3)
List(2, 2, 2)
List(2, 2, 3)
List(2, 3, 3)
List(3, 3, 3)

scala> gen(7, -3, 4) take 10 foreach println
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -1)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, 0)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, 1)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, 2)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, 3)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -1)
List(-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, 0)
```

Comment: nice one, +1. Only a minor stylistic remark: `1 to limit iterator` is hard to read, and it raises a postfix-operator warning. I would argue that `(1 to limit).iterator` is clearer.

Comment: The order is different than what you'd have using the for comprehension as in my example. e.g. for 3,4 it should be: 1 1 1 - 1 1 2 - 1 1 3 - 1 2 2 - 1 2 3, etc

Answer (score 2):

Well this works:

```
def intsIterator(n: Int, limit: Int) = (1 to n).map(List.fill(limit)(_)).flatten.combinations(limit).filter(l => (l, l.tail).zipped.forall(_ <= _))

scala> intsIterator(5,3) mkString "\n"
res16: String =
Vector(1, 2, 3)
Vector(1, 2, 4)
Vector(1, 2, 5)
Vector(1, 3, 4)
Vector(1, 3, 5)
Vector(1, 4, 5)
Vector(2, 3, 4)
Vector(2, 3, 5)
Vector(2, 4, 5)
Vector(3, 4, 5)
```

Basically you get a combination i.e. `n C limit` and then you filter based on if a list is sorted or not.

Or a more readable version:

```
def intsIterator(n: Int, limit: Int) = (1 to n).map(List.fill(limit)(_)).flatten.combinations(limit).filter(l => l.sorted == l)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Try this: intsIterator(10, 10000).take(100) foreach println

Comment: I like this, as it wont stack overflow, its a little inefficient though since it has to filter in quite an exhaustive way

Comment: @TrustNoOne It does now. I had a wrong assumption that there can be no duplicates. Now it works as you expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency or scalability where important I would act on `Vector`s, I wouldn't use recursion and create an `Iterator` instead of a `List`

```
new Iterator() {
  val max = limit - 1 // makes logic simpler
  var cur = Vector.fill(n - 1)(1) :+ 0
  var (i, v) = (n - 1, 1)

  def hasNext(): Boolean = cur.head != max

  def next(): List[Int] = {
    if (v <= max) 
      cur = cur.updated(i, v)
    else {
      i -= 1
      if (cur(i) == max - 1) 
        cur = cur.update(i, max)
      else {
        v = cur(i) + 1
        cur = cur.take(i) ++ Vector.fill(n - i)(v)
        i = n - 1
      }
    }
    v += 1
    cur.toList // you could leave as a Vector
  }
}
```

Of course you could always turn this into a `List` with `toList`

(Not tested; wrote with phone)